# Isolate x and find derivative of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to isolate x from this equation:

$$0.6^{x+2}-x-2 = 0$$

I know I need to use logarithms somehow and then I need to find a derivative of isolated x. Tried to use wolfram suggestions with no luck. Hope to find suggestions/help from mathematics community. Thanks.

Comment: There is no nice way to solve for $x$ using elementary functions.  It is possible to approximate $x$ numerically, and we can find $x$ exactly using advanced functions like the [Lambert $W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 1):

$$
y = x+2
$$
results in
$$
0.6^y -y =  \mathrm{e}^{y\ln(0.6)} -y = 0
$$
thus
$$
y\mathrm{e}^{-y\ln(0.6)} = 1
$$
let $z = -y\ln(0.6)$ then
$$
\frac{-1}{\ln(0.6)}ze^z = 1
$$
or
$$
z\mathrm{e}^z = -\ln(0.6) = \ln(5/3)
$$
or
$$
z = W(\ln(5/3))
$$
where $W$ is the lambert function
or
$$
x = \frac{1}{\ln(5/3)}W(\ln(5/3))-2
$$
but this is dependent if you consider the Lambert as a solution..

Comment: It's somewhat circular, as that function is defined to make the equality hold. It's as if I say what $\pi$, oh well it equals $\pi$. Calculating $W$ is the same problem he was asking in the first place.

Comment: I know right? But it does look pretty :). I will convert to a community post as it is not really a solution in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** the solution $x_0$ is the $x$ intercept of the graphs of $y = 0.6^{x+2}$ and $y = x+2$, and using W.A I got $x_0 \approx -1.30047$.

Comment: I don't need a solution, I need isolated x.

Comment: You can't isolate $x$.